# What's AMI ImageType?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

There is a image-type in describe-images filter, and an ImageType in response, however no information about what it stands for, and cannot find any information by googling.

There are three types: machine, kernel, ramdisk, what do they mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are just **using** AMI images provided by someone else, you can just ignore them -- you'll only need to use the AMI identifier when booting new instances.

A bit more detailed answer: The ramdisk image (ARI) and kernel image (AKI) are used as part of the boot sequence of a Linux instance.

More accurately:

- Hardware virtualized (HVM) instances do not use ARI or AKIs at all. All of the boot sequence is part of the AMI itself. This includes both EBS and instance-store backed instance types.
- Paravirtualized (PV e.g. running on Xen) EBS-backed instances need an AKI, and paravirtualized instance-backed instances need both AKI and ARI.

While AMIs are always unique, AKI/ARIs can be reused. For example, the `aki-88aa75e1` kernel image is used by (in `us-east-1`, public images) by 5413 AMIs and the ramdisk `ari-a51cf9cc` by 683 AMIs. Both of these images are provided by Amazon and are thus trusted by others when they're building AMIs. Also if you bundle an instance-store/paravirtualized machine as an AMI it'll will inherit ARI and AKI from original AMI so many people publishing AMIs will implicitly re-use those.

Also note that Windows requires HVM, so ARI/AKI are not applicable to Windows instances at all.

Some links for more information:

- https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=84096
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/UserProvidedKernels.html